# I am getting "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-table-v7

I am trying to fetch the posts data from the http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and displaying it in a table using react,redux and react-table.But i am getting the below error:
"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`."

Below is my code:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import store from "./Store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

###################################

App.js

import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const postsData = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch({ type: "save" });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  });

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "USER ID",
      accessor: "userId",
    },
    {
      Header: "ID",
      accessor: "id",
    },

    {
      Header: "Title",
      accessor: "title",
    },
    {
      Header: "Body",
      accessor: "body",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactTable data={postsData} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
#################################

Store.js

import { createStore } from "redux";

const postsReducer = (state = { posts: "null" }, action) => {
  if (action.type === "save") {
    return {
      posts: state.posts,
    };
  }

  return state;
};

const store = createStore(postsReducer);

export default store;
```

Comment: Are you using react-table v7 as specified in your tags? If that's the case, then you cannot do the following `import ReactTable from "react-table";`, you should use the `useTable` hook instead.

Comment: yes,i am using react table 7.Thanks, i will try with useTable hook.